# Accessing a button in a repeater from Code Behind (C#)

Tags: asp.net, button, repeater

I am finding some serious problems in accessing a button placed in a repeater from code behind.

This is the repeater code:

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

                    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Username:</td>
                                <td> <%# Eval("UserName") %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date:</td>
                                <td><%# Eval("CommentTime") %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Comment:</td>
                                <td><%# Eval("Comment") %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Text="Delete" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:Repeater>
```

And This is the code Behind placed int the page load:

```
  Button btn = new Button();
                    btn = (Button)Repeater1.FindControl("btnDeleteComment");
                    btn.Visible = false;
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: can u tell why are u doing button visible false?

Comment: Because i want that only the author of that comment can delete it! In fact the visibility of the button is setted in a if statement that cheks the username

Answer (score 3):

I am sure, I've solved your problem as to why you are getting the `object reference not set`.

As you have this conditional statement, `if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)`, when its first iterates it will be a header item type. Since your your button is in the item template, that's doesn't exist in the Header template.

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{ 
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
     Button btn = new Button(); 
     btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnDeleteComment"); 
     btn.Visible = false; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find the control like this. What you need to do is attach an event to repeater "item data bound event" and in that event handler do:

```
(Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnDeleteComment");
```

Comment: If I change code in this way the error object reference not set appears.     `protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
                        
                    Button btn = new Button();
                    btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnDeleteComment");
                    btn.Visible = false;
                   
           
        }`

Answer (score 0):

on .aspx

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" Text="Delete" Visible='<# IsAuthor?"true":"false" >' />
```

in code behind

```
//global  scope  
public bool IsAuthor=false;

//in pageload event

IsAuthor= GetIsAuthor();
```

Comment: Ok i will try this method and I will let you know